# 14.04 High Load Average - but no CPU

Tags: 14.04, system

I've got as system with 6 hperthreaded cores and 64Gb of RAM, just stood up 14.04 wit KVM, and I'm seeing load averages above 50, with only a VM install going on.  NO high CPU, NO high I/O, just crazy load average. It also fluctuates all over.

Any suggestions on where to look greatly appreciated

Here's top:

```
top - 15:26:40 up  1:12,  4 users,  load average: 13.88, 43.19, 47.55
Tasks: 317 total,   2 running, 315 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.5 us,  0.2 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:  65875788 total,  3212520 used, 62663268 free,    46440 buffers
KiB Swap: 67006460 total,        0 used, 67006460 free.   930788 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 1799 root      20   0  967124  28012  16468 S   2.7  0.0   1:52.95 libvirtd
 3117 clayj     20   0 1812296 125540  75520 S   1.3  0.2   0:47.47 compiz
 3413 clayj     20   0  824264  78264  42104 S   1.0  0.1   0:42.36 python
   96 root      25   5       0      0      0 S   0.7  0.0   0:14.71 ksmd
 1909 root      20   0  334452  52452  32264 S   0.7  0.1   0:41.59 Xorg
 2589 clayj     20   0  566476  27648  22384 S   0.7  0.0   0:26.33 psensor
 3332 clayj     20   0  687624  33600  24828 S   0.7  0.1   0:58.30 psensor
   25 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.3  0.0   0:00.79 rcuos/2
  781 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.3  0.0   0:07.82 kworker/4:+
 2836 clayj     20   0   40112   3452   2144 S   0.3  0.0   0:00.80 dbus-daemon
 2966 clayj     20   0  492636  27664  19716 S   0.3  0.0   0:01.01 unity-pane+
 3452 libvirt+  20   0 6976880 1.284g  16872 S   0.3  2.0   2:06.23 qemu-syste+
 8860 clayj     20   0   25076   3064   2432 R   0.3  0.0   0:02.23 top
10110 clayj     20   0   25080   3128   2496 R   0.3  0.0   0:00.14 top
    1 root      20   0   34104   4700   2692 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.98 init
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd
    3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/0
```

And here's PS

```
clayj@VMHOST1:~$ ps ax
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
    1 ?        Ss     0:00 /sbin/init
    2 ?        S      0:00 [kthreadd]
    3 ?        S      0:00 [ksoftirqd/0]
    5 ?        S<     0:00 [kworker/0:0H]
    7 ?        S      0:04 [rcu_sched]
    8 ?        S      0:00 [rcu_bh]
    9 ?        S      0:04 [rcuos/0]
   10 ?        S      0:00 [rcuob/0]
   11 ?        S      0:00 [migration/0]
   12 ?        S      0:00 [watchdog/0]
   13 ?        S      0:00 [watchdog/1]
   14 ?        S      0:00 [migration/1]
   15 ?        S      0:00 [ksoftirqd/1]
   16 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/1:0]
   17 ?        S<     0:00 [kworker/1:0H]
   18 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/1]
   19 ?        S      0:00 [rcuob/1]
   20 ?        S      0:00 [watchdog/2]
   21 ?        S      0:00 [migration/2]
   22 ?        S      0:00 [ksoftirqd/2]
   23 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/2:0]
   24 ?        S<     0:00 [kworker/2:0H]
   25 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/2]
   26 ?        S      0:00 [rcuob/2]
   27 ?        S      0:00 [watchdog/3]
   28 ?        S      0:00 [migration/3]
   29 ?        S      0:00 [ksoftirqd/3]
   31 ?        S<     0:00 [kworker/3:0H]
   32 ?        S      0:03 [rcuos/3]
   33 ?        S      0:00 [rcuob/3]
   34 ?        S      0:00 [watchdog/4]
   35 ?        S      0:00 [migration/4]
   36 ?        S      0:00 [ksoftirqd/4]
   37 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/4:0]
   38 ?        S<     0:00 [kworker/4:0H]
   39 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/4]
   40 ?        S      0:00 [rcuob/4]
   41 ?        S      0:00 [watchdog/5]
   42 ?        S      0:00 [migration/5]
   43 ?        S      0:00 [ksoftirqd/5]
   45 ?        S<     0:00 [kworker/5:0H]
   46 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/5]
   47 ?        S      0:00 [rcuob/5]
   48 ?        S      0:00 [watchdog/6]
   49 ?        S      0:00 [migration/6]
   50 ?        S      0:00 [ksoftirqd/6]
   51 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/6:0]
   52 ?        S<     0:00 [kworker/6:0H]
   53 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/6]
   54 ?        S      0:00 [rcuob/6]
   55 ?        S      0:00 [watchdog/7]
   56 ?        S      0:00 [migration/7]
   57 ?        S      0:00 [ksoftirqd/7]
   58 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/7:0]
   59 ?        S<     0:00 [kworker/7:0H]
   60 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/7]
   61 ?        S      0:00 [rcuob/7]
   62 ?        S      0:00 [watchdog/8]
   63 ?        S      0:00 [migration/8]
   64 ?        S      0:00 [ksoftirqd/8]
   65 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/8:0]
   66 ?        S<     0:00 [kworker/8:0H]
   67 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/8]
   68 ?        S      0:00 [rcuob/8]
   69 ?        S      0:00 [watchdog/9]
   70 ?        S      0:00 [migration/9]
   71 ?        S      0:00 [ksoftirqd/9]
   72 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/9:0]
   73 ?        S<     0:00 [kworker/9:0H]
   74 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/9]
   75 ?        S      0:00 [rcuob/9]
   76 ?        S      0:00 [watchdog/10]
   77 ?        S      0:00 [migration/10]
   78 ?        S      0:00 [ksoftirqd/10]
   79 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/10:0]
   80 ?        S<     0:00 [kworker/10:0H]
   81 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/10]
   82 ?        S      0:00 [rcuob/10]
   83 ?        S      0:00 [watchdog/11]
   84 ?        S      0:00 [migration/11]
   85 ?        S      0:00 [ksoftirqd/11]
   86 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/11:0]
   87 ?        S<     0:00 [kworker/11:0H]
   88 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/11]
   89 ?        S      0:00 [rcuob/11]
   90 ?        S<     0:00 [khelper]
   91 ?        S      0:00 [kdevtmpfs]
   92 ?        S<     0:00 [netns]
   93 ?        S<     0:00 [perf]
   94 ?        S      0:00 [khungtaskd]
   95 ?        S<     0:00 [writeback]
   96 ?        SN     0:15 [ksmd]
   97 ?        SN     0:00 [khugepaged]
   98 ?        S<     0:00 [crypto]
   99 ?        S<     0:00 [kintegrityd]
  100 ?        S<     0:00 [bioset]
  101 ?        S<     0:00 [kblockd]
  102 ?        S<     0:00 [ata_sff]
  103 ?        S<     0:00 [md]
  104 ?        S<     0:00 [devfreq_wq]
  105 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/u24:1]
  106 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/0:1]
  108 ?        S      0:00 [kswapd0]
  109 ?        S<     0:00 [vmstat]
  110 ?        S      0:00 [fsnotify_mark]
  111 ?        S      0:00 [ecryptfs-kthrea]
  122 ?        S<     0:00 [kthrotld]
  123 ?        S<     0:00 [acpi_thermal_pm]
  124 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/11:1]
  125 ?        S      0:01 [kworker/4:1]
  129 ?        S<     0:00 [ipv6_addrconf]
  150 ?        S<     0:00 [deferwq]
  151 ?        S<     0:00 [charger_manager]
  161 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/7:1]
  215 ?        S<     0:00 [kpsmoused]
  217 ?        S      0:00 [scsi_eh_0]
  218 ?        S<     0:00 [scsi_tmf_0]
  219 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/u24:3]
  220 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/3:1]
  221 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/5:1]
  225 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/2:3]
  229 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/9:1]
  230 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/1:1]
  232 ?        S<     0:00 [ttm_swap]
  275 ?        S<     0:00 [bioset]
  284 ?        S      0:00 [jbd2/sda2-8]
  285 ?        S<     0:00 [ext4-rsv-conver]
  298 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/10:1]
  317 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/8:1]
  323 ?        S<     0:00 [kworker/0:1H]
  465 ?        S<     0:00 [kworker/2:1H]
  476 ?        S      0:00 upstart-udev-bridge --daemon
  482 ?        Ss     0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd --daemon
  631 ?        S<     0:00 [rpciod]
  641 ?        S<     0:00 [nfsiod]
  644 ?        S<     0:00 [edac-poller]
  647 ?        S      0:00 [irq/50-mei_me]
  664 ?        S<     0:00 [kworker/9:1H]
  692 ?        Ss     0:00 rpc.idmapd
  694 ?        Ss     0:00 dbus-daemon --system --fork
  750 ?        S<     0:00 [kvm-irqfd-clean]
  759 ?        S<     0:00 [led_workqueue]
  773 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/bluetoothd
  781 ?        S<     0:08 [kworker/4:1H]
  792 ?        Ss     0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-logind
  793 ?        Ssl    0:00 rsyslogd
  796 ?        S      0:00 avahi-daemon: running [VMHOST1.local]
  801 ?        S      0:00 avahi-daemon: chroot helper
  814 ?        S<     0:00 [krfcommd]
  825 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/6:3]
 1003 ?        S      0:00 upstart-file-bridge --daemon
 1044 ?        Ss     0:00 smbd -F
 1051 ?        Ss     0:00 rpcbind
 1057 ?        Ss     0:00 rpc.statd -L
 1069 ?        S      0:00 upstart-socket-bridge --daemon
 1184 ?        S      0:00 smbd -F
 1205 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/winbindd -F
 1212 ?        Ss     0:00 nmbd -D
 1220 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/winbindd -F
 1280 ?        S<     0:00 [kworker/1:1H]
 1352 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/cupsd -f
 1355 ?        S      0:00 /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus dbus://
 1371 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/cups-browsed
 1495 ?        Ssl    0:00 /sbin/zfs-fuse --pidfile /var/run/zfs-fuse.pid
 1655 tty4     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty4
 1659 tty5     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty5
 1671 tty2     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty2
 1672 tty3     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty3
 1675 tty6     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty6
 1713 ?        Ss     0:00 atd
 1720 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
 1729 ?        Ss     0:00 cron
 1736 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/irqbalance
 1752 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/kerneloops
 1757 ?        Ssl    0:00 whoopsie
 1799 ?        Sl     1:55 /usr/sbin/libvirtd -d
 1812 ?        S      0:00 [kauditd]
 1828 ?        S      0:06 Xtightvnc :1 -desktop X -auth /home/clayj/.Xauthority
 1832 ?        Ss     0:00 acpid -c /etc/acpi/events -s /var/run/acpid.socket
 1874 ?        SLsl   0:00 lightdm
 1909 tty7     Ss+    0:42 /usr/bin/X -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightd
 1912 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/accountsservice/accounts-daemon
 1917 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkitd --no-debug
 1997 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --conf-file=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmas
 2047 ?        Sl     0:00 lightdm --session-child 12 19
 2080 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/upower/upowerd
 2127 ?        SNl    0:00 /usr/lib/rtkit/rtkit-daemon
 2207 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/colord/colord
 2426 ?        S      0:00 /bin/sh /etc/xdg/xfce4/xinitrc -- /etc/X11/xinit/xser
 2478 tty1     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1
 2485 ?        Sl     0:00 xfce4-session
 2488 ?        S      0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-launch --sh-syntax --exit-with-session
 2489 ?        Ss     0:00 //bin/dbus-daemon --fork --print-pid 5 --print-addres
 2492 ?        S      0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/xfconf/xfconfd
 2496 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent -s
 2497 ?        S      0:00 xfwm4 --display :1.0 --sm-client-id 2ddf16273-8e68-45
 2499 ?        S      0:00 Thunar --sm-client-id 228ae608a-5313-4a9f-b01f-fe6641
 2500 ?        Sl     0:00 xfce4-panel --display :1.0 --sm-client-id 2c3329af8-c
 2502 ?        Sl     0:00 xfdesktop --display :1.0 --sm-client-id 26d147f7b-050
 2503 ?        Ssl    0:00 xfsettingsd --display :1.0 --sm-client-id 26e3e62d0-a
 2507 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd
 2511 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-fuse /run/user/1000/gvfs -f -o bi
 2522 ?        Ssl    0:00 xfce4-power-manager --restart --sm-client-id 2cb8dec7
 2524 ?        Sl     0:00 update-notifier
 2526 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-sound/indicator-s
 2528 ?        Sl     0:00 zeitgeist-datahub
 2531 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/at-spi2-core/at-spi-bus-launcher
 2536 ?        S      0:00 xscreensaver -no-splash
 2541 ?        S      0:00 /bin/dbus-daemon --config-file=/etc/at-spi2/accessibi
 2544 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-bluetooth/indicat
 2546 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/share/system-config-printer/appl
 2549 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/at-spi2-core/at-spi2-registryd --use-gnome-s
 2553 ?        S<l    0:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
 2560 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-power/indicator-p
 2565 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/deja-dup/deja-dup-monitor
 2571 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/bin/zeitgeist-daemon
 2574 ?        Ssl    0:00 xfce4-volumed
 2580 ?        S<     0:00 [kworker/11:1H]
 2581 ?        Ss     0:00 xfce4-power-manager
 2585 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-application/indic
 2588 ?        S      0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/panel/wrapper-1.0 /us
 2589 ?        Sl     0:26 psensor
 2593 ?        S      0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/panel/wrapper-1.0 /us
 2599 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/zeitgeist-fts
 2604 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor
 2622 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authenticatio
 2625 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/notify-osd
 2632 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/udisks2/udisksd --no-debug
 2657 ?        S      0:00 /bin/cat
 2660 ?        S      0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconf/gconfd-2
 2661 ?        S<     0:00 [kworker/3:1H]
 2663 ?        S<     0:00 [kworker/7:1H]
 2670 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-afc-volume-monitor
 2676 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-mtp-volume-monitor
 2680 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor
 2691 ?        Sl     0:04 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-trash --spawner :1.8 /org/gtk/gvf
 2731 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/winbindd -F
 2744 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --daemonize --login
 2746 ?        Ss     0:00 init --user
 2836 ?        Ss     0:00 dbus-daemon --fork --session --address=unix:abstract=
 2847 ?        Ss     0:00 upstart-event-bridge
 2857 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hud/window-stack-bridge
 2891 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/bamf/bamfdaemon
 2893 ?        S      0:00 upstart-file-bridge --daemon --user
 2895 ?        S      0:00 upstart-dbus-bridge --daemon --system --user --bus-na
 2897 ?        S      0:00 upstart-dbus-bridge --daemon --session --user --bus-n
 2902 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd
 2912 ?        Ssl    0:05 /usr/bin/ibus-daemon --daemonize --xim
 2928 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/lib/unity-settings-daemon/unity-settings-daemon
 2932 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/ibus/ibus-dconf
 2934 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hud/hud-service
 2935 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/ibus/ibus-ui-gtk3
 2940 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/ibus/ibus-x11 --kill-daemon
 2941 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/lib/at-spi2-core/at-spi-bus-launcher --launch-im
 2942 ?        Ssl    0:00 gnome-session --session=ubuntu
 2956 ?        S      0:00 /bin/dbus-daemon --config-file=/etc/at-spi2/accessibi
 2966 ?        Ssl    0:01 /usr/lib/unity/unity-panel-service
 2971 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/at-spi2-core/at-spi2-registryd --use-gnome-s
 2993 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-keyboard-service
 2995 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-messages/indicato
 2998 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-bluetooth/indicat
 3001 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-power/indicator-p
 3002 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-datetime/indicato
 3005 ?        Sl     0:01 /usr/lib/ibus/ibus-engine-simple
 3008 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-sound/indicator-s
 3017 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-printers/indicato
 3019 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-session/indicator
 3023 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-application/indic
 3041 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/notify-osd
 3055 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-source-registry
 3076 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-calendar-factory
 3095 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/dconf/dconf-service
 3100 ?        S<     0:00 [kworker/8:1H]
 3117 ?        Sl     0:48 compiz
 3123 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authenticatio
 3124 ?        Sl     0:00 nautilus -n
 3127 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/unity-settings-daemon/unity-fallback-mount-h
 3146 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor
 3152 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-afc-volume-monitor
 3157 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-mtp-volume-monitor
 3161 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor
 3167 ?        Sl     0:04 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-trash --spawner :1.6 /org/gtk/gvf
 3173 ?        S<     0:00 [kworker/5:1H]
 3176 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-burn --spawner :1.6 /org/gtk/gvfs
 3187 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/unity-scope-home/unity-scop
 3198 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/bin/unity-scope-loader applications/applications
 3200 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/unity-lens-files/unity-file
 3211 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/bin/zeitgeist-daemon
 3219 ?        Sl     0:00 zeitgeist-datahub
 3269 ?        Sl     0:07 gnome-terminal
 3275 ?        S      0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconf/gconfd-2
 3278 ?        S      0:00 gnome-pty-helper
 3279 pts/5    Ss     0:00 bash
 3295 ?        Sl     0:00 telepathy-indicator
 3301 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5
 3331 ?        S<     0:00 [kworker/6:1H]
 3332 ?        Sl     0:58 psensor
 3377 ?        Sl     0:00 update-notifier
 3384 ?        S      0:00 xterm
 3386 pts/0    Ss+    0:00 bash
 3410 pts/5    S      0:09 xosview +net
 3413 ?        Ssl    0:43 python /usr/share/virt-manager/virt-manager.py
 3452 ?        Sl     2:06 qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -name IntelDev -S -mac
 3453 ?        S      0:00 [vhost-3452]
 3456 ?        S      0:00 [kvm-pit/3452]
 3458 ?        S<     0:00 [kworker/10:1H]
 3495 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/deja-dup/deja-dup-monitor
 4075 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/5:2]
 4076 ?        S      0:01 [kworker/0:0]
 5998 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --start --foreground --
 8860 pts/5    S+     0:02 top
 9229 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/3:0]
 9669 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/lib/unity/unity-panel-service --lockscreen-mode
 9769 ?        Ss     0:00 sshd: clayj [priv]
 9858 ?        S      0:00 sshd: clayj@pts/16
 9859 pts/16   Ss     0:00 -bash
10276 pts/16   R+     0:00 ps ax
clayj@VMHOST1:~$
```

Comment: Please provide your computer make and model and your processor make and model (i.e. `grep "model name" /proc/cpuinfo`) and kernel version ( `uname -a` ).

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't have to be a lot of CPU usage, there just have to be a lot of processes trying to run. ["Each running process either using or waiting for CPU resources adds 1 to the load average."](http://www.howtogeek.com/194642/understanding-the-load-average-on-linux-and-other-unix-like-systems/)

Perhaps there are dozens of processes running but using very little processing power.

Comment: Not sure what the root cause was; but when I reconfigured networking (basically deleted all interfaces and started over) it seems to have gone away.